# R: sum columns using conditionals and row, column indexes

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, sum

I have a dataframe where there are many, many NA values interspersed among the columns of interest.  Here is a sample:

```
dput(try[, 30:34])
structure(list(adj_avg_2016 = c(25641966.4, 28919805, 44152549.8, 
4341304.9, 10588244.8, 4928398.6, 8985362.4, 832000, 2674875.2, 
20416846.8), adj_avg_2017 = c(27693728, 29815155, 46187854.8, 
4594589.9, 11021124.8, 5075010, 9436240.8, 848640, 2782821.6, 
21439365.4), adj_avg_2018 = c(31554678.4, 30710505, 45952664, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 865920, 2894427.2, 21556703.6), adj_avg_2019 = c(33454832, 
31605855, 45590832, NA, 12319764.8, NA, NA, 900480, NA, 
21556703.6), adj_avg_2020 = c(35122520, 32501205, 46495412, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3130445.6, 22520553.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

What I would like to do is sum each of the columns in the dataframe `try` based on a condition using the column index.

**More specifically, I would like to look at the previous year column and sum using only the elements that are non-NA in both the current and previous year column.  For example**

- For col `adj_avg_2016`, I want to sum all elements because it is the first column in the group
- For col `adj_avg_2017`, I want to sum all elements **because there are no NA values in it or in the `adj_avg_2016` column.**
- For col `adj_avg_2018`, I want to sum using only the *corresponding* entries that aren't `NA` in either `adj_avg_2017` or `adj_avg_2018` (so entries 1:3, 8:10)
- For col `adj_avg_2019`, I want to sum using entries 1:3, 8 & 10 **because entry 5 in `adj_avg_2018` is NA and entry 9 in `adj_avg_2019` is NA**
- For col `adj_avg_2020` I would like to sum using only entries 1:3 & 10 because entry 9 is empty in `adj_avg_2019`.

My desired result are columns for each year, `agg_pass1_2016`...`agg_pass1_2020` containing the specified calculations.

Since the dataframe will continue to grow each year and I will be doing this quite a bit a function seems like the way to go.  Here is what I came up with so far:

```
str <- function(df, overwrite = TRUE){
    nms <- grep("adj_avg_[0-9]+$", names(df), value = TRUE) # get the columns
    nms_col_idx <- grep("adj_avg_[0-9]+$", names(df), value = FALSE) # get the column indexes
    revnms <- gsub("adj_avg", "agg_pass1", nms) # names of new columns I want to add
    if(!overwrite) revnms <- setdiff(revnms, names(df))
    df[, revnms] <- lapply(df[, nms], sum, ....) # This is where I get confused.
}
```

My problems/questions:

1. What is the best way to incorporate the row and column indexes into `df[, revnms]` in the above function to achieve the desired calculations?  I know one way would involve some combination of `which(!is.na(.))` but am unsure of how to put that into my function in the last row.
2. Is there another function that could achieve my results as quickly and simply as a function?

All comments/suggestions are welcome.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't this just `colSums(try, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: At least in your example, it seems like `NA` values can be introduced going across a row, but they never go away so akrun's suggestion looks like it will work just fine. If this isn't the case in your real data, I'd suggest editing your question to provide a more realistic sample.

Comment: @akrun I have updated the sample data to better reflect my desired outcome.  Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: based on this logic `elements that are non-NA in both the current and previous year column.` the last one should be `1-3` and `10`? because 9 is NA in `adj_avg_2019`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the logic, we may need to multiply with the logical matrix created with the subset of data without the first column and the last column to and get the `colSums`

```
colSums(cbind(try[1], try[-1] * (!is.na(try[-1]) & 
         !is.na(try[-ncol(try)]))), na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
adj_avg_2016 adj_avg_2017 adj_avg_2018 adj_avg_2019 adj_avg_2020 
   151481354    158894530    133534898    133108703    136639690
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
try %>%
    summarise(across(everything(),
     ~ if(cur_column() == 'adj_avg_2016') sum(., na.rm = TRUE) 
     else sum(.x[!is.na(.x) &  
      !is.na(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "(\\d+)$",
       function(x) as.numeric(x) - 1)))])))
  adj_avg_2016 adj_avg_2017 adj_avg_2018 adj_avg_2019 adj_avg_2020
1    151481354    158894530    133534898    133108703    136639690
```

If we want to create new columns, use `mutate` instead of `summarise` and also make use of `.names`

```
try %>%
    mutate(across(everything(),
     ~ if(cur_column() == 'adj_avg_2016') sum(., na.rm = TRUE) 
     else sum(.x[!is.na(.x) &  
      !is.na(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "(\\d+)$",
       function(x) as.numeric(x) - 1)))]), 
      .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'avg', 'pass')}"))
```

-output

```
   adj_avg_2016 adj_avg_2017 adj_avg_2018 adj_avg_2019 adj_avg_2020 adj_pass_2016 adj_pass_2017 adj_pass_2018 adj_pass_2019 adj_pass_2020
1      25641966     27693728     31554678     33454832     35122520     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
2      28919805     29815155     30710505     31605855     32501205     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
3      44152550     46187855     45952664     45590832     46495412     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
4       4341305      4594590           NA           NA           NA     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
5      10588245     11021125           NA     12319765           NA     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
6       4928399      5075010           NA           NA           NA     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
7       8985362      9436241           NA           NA           NA     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
8        832000       848640       865920       900480           NA     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
9       2674875      2782822      2894427           NA      3130446     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
10     20416847     21439365     21556704     21556704     22520553     151481354     158894530     133534898     133108703     136639690
```

Comment: yes the calculations are correct, I'm just unsure of how to fit it into my function because I need to be able to create variables `agg_pass1_[0-9]+$` for each year.

Comment: @jvalenti in the first solution, it assumes that the columns are in order.  So, when we do the `try[-1]`, it removes the first column, and `try[-ncol(try)]`, the last column to make the column lag/lead and to make them in same dimensions.  With `&`, it will do the comparison on the  previous corresponding column.  With `tidyverse`, it is actually getting the column names with `cur_column()`, so you don't have to worry about the the column name order as we are doing `as.numeric(x) -1`

Comment: @jvalenti are you creating new columns with the sum. on ech column, i.e. changing tthe 'avg' to 'pass', then you may need `mutate` instead of `summarise` and make use of `.names` i.e. `.names = "{str_replace(.col, 'avg', 'pass')}"`

Comment: ok, I am starting to see what you did...quick question.  what does the `.` before `names` and `x` mean?  And what if Ithe columns given are simply a subset of my dataframe?  `everything` seems to imply that the function will be applied to all columns...I don't want that.

Comment: @jvalenti Those are parameters in `across`.  If you check the docs, it is the usage `across(.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL)` - `.names - A glue specification that describes how to name the output columns. This can use {.col} to stand for the selected column name, and {.fn} to stand for the name of the function being applied. The default (NULL) is equivalent to "{.col}" for the single function case and "{.col}_{.fn}" for the case where a list is used for .fns.`

Comment: and how would I divide `cur_column()` by the previous year column?

Comment: @jvalenti we changed the substring with `str_replace` ie.. `(\\d+)$` refers to one or more digits at the end (`$`) of the string is captured and is replaced by subtracting 1 `function(x) as.numeric(x) - 1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239407/discussion-between-jvalenti-and-akrun).